# Colocar registros em uma linha apenas

Tags: sql

Problema: O usuário faz vários logins e vários logouts, queria colocar o login e logout na mesma linha ao lado do nome do usuário, com a data de login e a data de logout, na mesma linha. Todos os registros em uma linha só.

Comment: tabela - sistema

Comment: E qual o banco também...

Comment: Posta a estrutura da tabela, são só essas 3 colunas? tem o ID do usuário?

Comment: Como deixar na mesma linha? na aplicação? no banco já é estruturado em colunas

Comment: Acredito que você deva consultar as operações de login e concatenar com a operação de logout mais próxima. Mas ainda sim terá problemas caso não existam operações de login e logout registradas de forma consistente.

Ex.: O usuário efetua o login a partir de A e depois B, faz o logout em B e depois em A, como você vai saber qual operação de fim tem relação com a de início?

Você precisa ainda de uma coluna indicando a sessão das operações, sendo que quando não houver logout a informação ficaria em branco.

Answer (score 0):

eu utilizaria manipulação de log para este tipo de tarefa
creio que sql nao seria a melhor forma para saber quando o usuario entrou ou saiu da sessão.

recomendo você dar uma olhada em manipulação de arquivos .txt

ou alterar a tabela da database para seguinte forma

| id | usuario | ultimo_login | ultimo_logout |

> CREATE TABLE nometabela(
>
> id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
>
> usuario VARCHAR(60),
>
> ultimo_login VARCHAR(30),
>
> ultimo_logout VARCHAR(30)
>
> );

coloquei as datas da tabela como string por que nao sei atraves de qual linguagem você vai trabalhar.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer essa consulta utilizando uma subquery.

Veja funcionando: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ada005/2)

```
SELECT 
  s1.nomusuario [Usuario]
  , 'Login/Logout'
  , s1.data [Login]
  , (
    SELECT MIN(data)
    FROM sistema [s2] 
    WHERE s2.nomusuario = s1.nomusuario
    AND s2.operacao = 'logout'
    AND s2.data > s1.data
  )
FROM sistema [s1]
WHERE s1.operacao = 'login'
```

Comment: essa solução só atende o cenário onde existe apenas um registro de operação (login/logout) para cada usuário.